# Mysql Query - Display rows that found match in few tables and display empty rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on one table, this table holds for example, customer number, this customer number is found in two other tables that I want to pull details about this number ( name, phone tec.).
So my query displays only customers that have a match in the query of some CODE Number, this is because i`m using INNER Join.

I want to display rows that don't have match in the other tables. They are in the table that I select from but don't have the code number. (like an empty row that I want to display)
The next query will be more understandable

```
$sql="SELECT $tbl_name.*,customers.fname,eventcodes.DISCODE,eventcodes.AREA
                FROM $tbl_name
                    INNER JOIN customers
                        INNER JOIN eventcodes
                                ON $tbl_name.Ccode=eventcodes.MokedCcode AND eventcodes.Ccode=customers.Ccode  AND $tbl_name.CODE=eventcodes.CODE
                                                                ORDER By `id` DESC
                                                                        LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

As you can see all the rows I want to display found on $tbl_name, this query work but it display to me only the rows that match the conditions, I want to display all the rows from the table those that don't have CODE, but I can pull their name for example (fname) from the customers table because I have their code (customer number).
Thanks!

Comment: try to use LEFT or RIGHT Join in sted of INNER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and watch out the join conditions:

```
SELECT 
  t.*,
  c.fname,
  e.DISCODE,
  e.AREA
FROM $tbl_name       AS t
LEFT JOIN customers  AS c ON t.Ccode = c.Ccode
LEFT JOIN eventcodes AS e ON t.Ccode = e.MokedCcode 
ORDER By `id` DESC
LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

**Note that:** I moved the condition `customers.Ccode = $tablename.Ccode` to the first join, and removed the condition `$tbl_name.CODE=eventcodes.CODE`, Since the first two joins will insure that condition.

Comment: its giving me those that dont have the CODE. just them.

Comment: @OfirAttia - What do you mean? Can you please edit your question with some sample data from the three tables explaining this issue? this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT $tbl_name.*,customers.fname,eventcodes.DISCODE,eventcodes.AREA
                FROM $tbl_name
                    LEFT JOIN customers
                        LEFT JOIN eventcodes
                                ON $tbl_name.Ccode=eventcodes.MokedCcode AND eventcodes.Ccode=customers.Ccode  AND $tbl_name.CODE=eventcodes.CODE
                                                                ORDER By `id` DESC
                                                                        LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` insted of `INNER JOIN`